# Problems creating a icon

Tags: java, url, embedded-resource

I have problems trying to create an ImageIcon for my project. My createImageIcon method goes as follows ::

```
 protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description)
   {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) 
    {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } 
    else 
      {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
      }
   }
```

And the line that creates the Icon ::

```
      ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("**ICON URL***","Java");
```

Unfortunately, I cannot create any Icon because all the URLs I enter are not found (the file is not found). Could someone please tell me how to get the URL of an image found online that will work and will fit for this method? Thanks.

Comment: Use `ImageIO.read` instead.  It will at least thrown an exception when the image can't be loaded with a reason, which infinitely better then `ImageIcon` which swallows then silently.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: Using `Class#getResource` suggests that the images are "embedded" (ie included in the Jar file/class path).  You should build and package you code and check the resulting Jar file to ensure that the images have been included as expected

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer for the suggestion to use ```ImageIO.read``` . It works nicely :)